# What makes a piece of writing good/attractive?

Tags: writing

I am trying to improve my English writing skills. But I don't know what a good piece of written work means and hence cannot set my goal/target. Does using hard/rare words and metaphors makes one's writing good?

P.S At present, I am reading a paragraph or two from a book, then I try to recall the content/fact of the para and then rewrite the whole two paras with the said fact in my own way and then compare two pieces of work. But most of the time I end up mimicking the author. I guess this happens because I don't have an independent perspective on the said topic. Is this a good training method and how should I improve it to avoid the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: Absolutely not. They make it seem pretentious. They can only be safely used when the piece is already good.

Comment: The awkward moment when I had to look for the meaning of the word pretentious :-)

Comment: First, you need to figure out what you mean by "good writing." Is it writing that sells well?  Writing that certain kinds of people enjoy?  Writing that's persuasive?  All of these things are aspects of good writing and each of them have different demands. Mimicry is probably useful, as long as you don't think good writing must be totally original.

Comment: I think the question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Or you want to improve the visual aspect of your writing? Learn calligraphy? Spelling? Speed?

Comment: @Juhasz Knowing what good writing is the question I am seeking an answer to. My vague idea is, if I have a brilliant idea that I am excited about, my writing should be good enough to convey the brilliance/excitement to the reader. My current problem is that my writing doesn't feel continuous. I have to end sentence abruptly and start a new one abruptly. I don't feel my writing has a certain flow which takes one idea to another in a seamless and smooth manner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to write belong at [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)—where they might not just be closed as opinion based, as they would here.